# Generating DART package from Swagger-codegen

Tags: flutter, dart, swagger-codegen

**EDITED** : 
I am getting new error now : I am using SWAGGER 2.0

Command :    `java -jar path/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json  -l dart -i dart    -o /Users/path/folder/ToStoreClient`

**ERROR :**

```
 [main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from dart
    [main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from dart
    [main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:764)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:299)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

I am trying to get DART package from the swagger url.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

I am able to implement all the package and steps done here for PETSTORE API :
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/dart-jaguar/swagger

But i am not able to create DART package from my swagger url in my MAC 
I tried installing Homebrew

```
brew install swagger-codegen
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i [PATH FOR SWAGGER] -l dart -i swagger.yaml          -o ./api-client -DbrowserClient=false
```

Below is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name dart Available: aspnetcore
csharp
csharp-dotnet2
dynamic-html
html
html2
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
jaxrs-cxf
inflector
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-spec
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-di
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-resteasy
spring
nodejs-server
openapi
openapi-yaml
kotlin-client
kotlin-server
php
python
python-flask
scala
scala-akka-http-server
swift3
swift4
typescript-angular

    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dart
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Is your API definition `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: I am using Swagger:2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you API definition is OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) you need to use Swagger Codegen version 2.x instead of 3.x. You can download 2.x CLI JAR from here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.12

Or, to install it using Homebrew, use:

```
brew install swagger-codegen@2
```

Also, you have some duplicate arguments in your command `-l dart -i dart`. You only need `-l dart`. `-i` is used to specify the API definition file (in your example - Petstore JSON file). The correct command is:

```
java -jar path/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l dart -o /Users/path/folder/ToStoreClient
```

Comment: ,Thank you for the reply. I did download Swagger:2.0 and also configure 2.4.12.jar file. But its still showing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!

Comment: This error is caused by an extra argument in your command - see the updated answer.