# Error while creating DART package for flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

**EDITED :** 
I edited my swagger path. But i am getting below error now.

```
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://SWAGGERFILE/api
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://SWAGGERFILE/api
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:764)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:299)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

Below is the command i am using in mac to generate dart package

```
java -jar /Users/PATH/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/src/main/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://SWAGGERFILE/api-docs/#/ -l dart -o /Users/PATH/STORE/DART/PACKAGE
```

It works fine for

```
 java -jar /Users/PATH/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/src/main/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l dart -o /Users/PATH/STORE/DART/PACKAGE
```

Below is the error i am getting :

```
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://SWAGGERFILE/api-docs/#/
[main] WARN io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils - Error snake-parsing yaml content
io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$SnakeException: Exception safe-checking yaml content  (maxDepth 2000)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:300)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:525)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:438)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:137)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.deserializeYaml(Swagger20Parser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.convertToSwagger(Swagger20Parser.java:125)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.read(Swagger20Parser.java:109)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:69)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 14, column 17:
          box-sizing: border-box;
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:869)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.peekToken(ScannerImpl.java:250)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentEnd.produce(ParserImpl.java:253)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:87)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:279)
    ... 10 more
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://production.user-api.api.findnemo.in/api-docs/#/
[main] WARN io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils - Error snake-parsing yaml content
io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$SnakeException: Exception safe-checking yaml content  (maxDepth 2000)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:300)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:525)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:438)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:137)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.deserializeYaml(Swagger20Parser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.convertToSwagger(Swagger20Parser.java:125)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.read(Swagger20Parser.java:109)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 14, column 17:
          box-sizing: border-box;
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:869)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.peekToken(ScannerImpl.java:250)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentEnd.produce(ParserImpl.java:253)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:87)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:279)
    ... 10 more
[main] ERROR io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />

  <style>
    html
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }"[truncated 2632 chars]; line: 2, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:637)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1917)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:194)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:123)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:764)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:299)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
shwetadodiya@shwetas-MBP swagger-codegen-master % java -jar /Users/shwetadodiya/Documents/FlutterProjects/Swagger/swagger-codegen-master/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/src/main/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://production.user-api.api.findnemo.in/api-docs/#/ -l dart -o /Users/shwetadodiya/Documents/FlutterProjects/Swagger/SwaggerCode 
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://production.user-api.api.findnemo.in/api-docs/#/
[main] WARN io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils - Error snake-parsing yaml content
io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$SnakeException: Exception safe-checking yaml content  (maxDepth 2000)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:300)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:525)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:438)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:137)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.deserializeYaml(Swagger20Parser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.convertToSwagger(Swagger20Parser.java:125)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.read(Swagger20Parser.java:109)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:69)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 14, column 17:
          box-sizing: border-box;
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:869)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.peekToken(ScannerImpl.java:250)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentEnd.produce(ParserImpl.java:253)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:87)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:279)
    ... 10 more
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://production.user-api.api.findnemo.in/api-docs/#/
[main] WARN io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils - Error snake-parsing yaml content
io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$SnakeException: Exception safe-checking yaml content  (maxDepth 2000)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:300)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:525)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:438)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:137)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.deserializeYaml(Swagger20Parser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.convertToSwagger(Swagger20Parser.java:125)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.read(Swagger20Parser.java:109)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 14, column 17:
          box-sizing: border-box;
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:869)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.peekToken(ScannerImpl.java:250)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentEnd.produce(ParserImpl.java:253)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:87)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData(DeserializationUtils.java:279)
    ... 10 more
[main] ERROR io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />

  <style>
    html
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }"[truncated 2632 chars]; line: 2, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:637)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1917)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:194)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:123)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:437)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:297)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:764)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:299)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-i` parameter expects the path to the OpenAPI YAML/JSON file. It looks like `https://SWAGGERFILE/api-docs/#/` points to an HTML page (e.g. Swagger UI) and not the actual OpenAPI YAML/JSON file.

If you use Swagger UI, here's how you can get the YAML/JSON file link:
[How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the path but now i am getting new error. I edited my question and mention then new error in that.

Comment: If you open `https://SWAGGERFILE/api` in a browser, do you see YAML/JSON? Like here - https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

Comment: Yes. I do see the JSON  which start like : {"openapi":"3.0.3.. when i open https://SWAGGERFILE/api in browser

Comment: https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json - This api start with {"swagger":"2.0" and the API which i am trying start with {"openapi":"3.0.3" ? Will that be the reason for the error ?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. If you have `openapi: 3.0.x` you need to use Swagger Codegen 3.x. Codegen 2.x is for `swagger: '2.0'` definitions only. The situation is similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60746161), but the other way round.

Comment: But Swagger Codegen 3.X  does not have dart file support. Is that right ?

Comment: Right. I forgot about that... A possible workaround is to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56637299/113116) your OpenAPI 3.0 definition to OpenAPI 2.0, and then use Codegen 2.x to generate the Dart client.